# OAuth redirect_uri to https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?xxx strips part of the query string

Tags: support, api-v2.2, oauth2

I have a browser extension that uses OAuth2 to retrieve an access token. As recommended by https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication, I use `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/login_success` as the value of `redirect_uri`.

To avoid inadvertently using the access token from other applications, I have [inserted a unique identifier in the URL](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/blob/3d9df0592a5a42d112b28adce8ddd82dc7dc7136/Chrome/stackexchange-inbox-api.js#L6-L11), so that the extension will only use access tokens that it has explicitly requested.

The URL for the OAuth is thus as follows:

`https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=903&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?robw&protocol=https&&scope=no_expiry,read_inbox`

Upon succesful authentication, it used to redirect to:
 `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?robw&protocol=https#access_token=XX`

A user recently reported that my extension was broken. This is apparently because they are redirected to the following instead:
`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?protocol=https#access_token=XX`

Is this a bug in OAuth (and will the value of `redirect_uri` be respected in a future update)? If not, what is the recommended way to authenticate users and avoid conflicts with other browser extensions that also use the recommended `redirect_uri` to authenticate users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's a bug, for implicit OAuth.  Anyway, if I understand *RFC 6749* correctly, that is not how you are supposed to do such extra checks.

**Use [the `state` parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1).**  And this works.

For example, a call to:
  [`/oauth/dialog?...&state=robfoo&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`](https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=903&scope=no_expiry,read_inbox&state=robfoo&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success)
(Click the link and try it.)

Yields results like:  
  `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=Qs...LUg))&state=robfoo`

When the user authorizes the app.