# How to get access token from the hash?

Tags: support, api, oauth2

I am trying to implement OAuth Stack Exchange API via Android app as client.
After a successful login from out I get the below URL how do I get or decode the access_token from the hash?

```
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=14702 &accountId=15559293 &scope=no_expiry &returnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2foauth%2fdialog%3fclient_id%3d14702%26scope%3dno_expiry%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success&nonce=HDE6GdCUbq90z7Uq6l8FHg))&ticks=636889445649720585&flowKind=Implicit&hash=6d3bbaad65ce8277bc8f357d8b594d63252ba270ee0fe163b11d1cac6e5583c6
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [the API Authentication docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication); there are a great many things wrong with the URL in the question (at least 5).

For starters, it's to the wrong path. `stackoverflow.com/oauth/authorize` gives helpful messages/results like:

- > Oops! Something Bad Happened!
- > Authorization attempt not valid for current user
- > Authorization attempt unauthorized
- > Couldn't parse `ticks` (etc)

None of these messages hint at the real problems.

Anyway the correct URL per the (incorrect) docs is `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog`.

### But it's more correct to use: `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog`.

All the [extra and redundant parameters you were passing are normally ignored](https://stackapps.com/questions/8233/oauth-redirect-uri-to-https-stackexchange-com-oauth-login-successxxx-strips-p) (or sometimes throw an error).

**The correct way to get an access token is like:**
    https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=14702&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
(Click it and see)

---

If you want **to pass additional security values,** they must be [the `state` parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1).
For example, calling:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=14702&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success&state=nonce=HDE6GdCU,ticks=636889445649720585
```

Note the **comma-separated values**.

The above call yields:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=nUh_no_peaking_f8xkByw))&state=nonce%3dHDE6GdCU%2cticks%3d636889445649720585
```

Where *state* `decodeURIComponent` decodes to: `state=nonce=HDE6GdCU,ticks=636889445649720585` (the value passed in).